# I wish to limit my resized divs to a min and max width

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am building a site built of a wordpress responsive theme as the parent.  I have a content section (content-blog) on the left side of the page and a sidebar (widgets) on the right side of the page.  I have them set to scale down with the browser size, However I would like to set a min-width to both so that they don't scrunch up on smaller browsers.  I want the sidebar to move underneath the main content at a certain width point.  Here are my html and css.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
    /* content */
  </div> <!-- end header -->

  <div id="container" class="hfeed">
    <div id="navigation">
     /*content */
   </div> <!-- end navigation -->

  <div id="feature">
   /* content */
  </div> <!-- end feature -->

  <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">

    <div id="content-blog" class="grid col-620">
     /*content */
    </div> <!-- end content-blog -->

    <div id="widgets" class="grid col-300 fit">
     /* content */
    </div> <!--end widgets -->
  </div> <!-- end wrapper -->

  <div id="footer"
   /* content */
  </div> <!--end of footer- -->

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2D2C2A;
 color: #2D2C2A;
}

#container {
 max-width: 1100px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 15px 
}

#wrapper {
 max-width: 1010px;
 width: 100%
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 15px;
 border: none;
}

#content-blog {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-top: 16px;
 max-width: 65%;
 min-width: 45%;
 width: auto;
}

#widgets {
 float: right;
 margin-top: 40px;
 max-width: 32%;
 width: auto;
}
```

The site is [podcastanswers.com](http://podcastanswers.com) if that helps also.   I have tried setting a min-width but no matter what as the browser scales down the divs continue to get smaller and never stop at the min setting.  I'm sure it something that I have missed or am not understanding but I haven't been able to find the answer in my searching.  Thank you all in advance.

Comment: setting up a fiddle is better than adding a link to the post because the link doesn't help future users should the web page change.

Comment: You probably want to use [CSS media queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/)

Comment: Why not press F12 and have a look at how the site you post actually works:) You can see that media query is used.

Answer (score 2):

The percentage metric is relative to the current size of the screen, not the one that was set when the browser loaded the page. So whenever you resize the screen, the `min-width`/`max-width` values change as well (not sure if this is exactly your issue since the example was rather lengthy) but, it seems like you are trying to make a responsive design and therefore you should use media-queries. An example code of media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1040px) and (min-width: 100px) {
    #content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Here are some resources that will help you understand and use them:

[CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)
[Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)